# Algorithm to find MST in a huge complete graph

Tags: algorithm, graph, computer-science, minimum-spanning-tree

Let's assume a complete graph of > 25000 nodes. Each node is essentially a point on a plane.
It has 625M edges. Each edge has length which should be stored as a floating point number.

I need an algorithm to find its MST (on a usual PC).

If I take Kruskal's algorithm, it needs to sort all edges first, but I cannot afford even store the edges altogether in memory at the same time.

If I choose Prim's algorithm, it's quite difficult to evaluate how many edges will be stored in a heap at the same time, but probably the most of them will be there very soon after algorithm starts.

Is there any more memory-sufficient algorithm which can allow me to avoid sorting edges stored in a file?

Also, are there any known MST algorithms which utilize the fact that any tree edges satisfy triangle inequality?

Comment: Is the graph complete? 625M is just 25000**2. Also, here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_minimum_spanning_tree

Comment: There are also library for this: http://www.mlpack.org/doxygen.php?doc=emst_tutorial.html

Comment: @ZiyaoWei: thanks, it looks like what I was seeking for.

Answer (score 6):

You can still use Kruskal's algorithm.

You don't actually need to sort the edges, what the algorithm requires is simply a method for repeatably finding the smallest weight edge that hasn't already been used. Presorting the edges and iterating through that list is simply a very efficient way of doing so.

You can do the same thing simply by repeatably find the k-smallest unused edges (where k is a manageable number, probably at least |V|), then sort and iterate through them instead as needed. This breaks the sorting process down into more manageable segments, although there is a time-space tradeoff as depending on how large k is the time complexity of this process can be anywhere from O(E log E) (k = E) to about O(E^2) (k = 1).

Answer (score 3):

[Boruvka's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boruvka%27s_algorithm) makes a logarithmic number of passes on the *unsorted* edge list. The memory required is proportional to the number of nodes.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this algorithm

```
1: Append weight w and outgoing vertex v per edge into a list, X.
2: Divide the edge-list, E, into segments with 1 indicating the start
of each segment, and 0 otherwise, store this in flag array F.
3: Perform segmented min scan on X with F indicating segments
to find minimum outgoing edge-index per vertex, store in NWE.
4: Find the successor of each vertex and add to successor array, S.
5: Remove cycle making edges from NWE using S, and identify
representatives vertices.
6: Mark remaining edges from NWE as part of output in MST.
7: Propagate representative vertex ids using pointer doubling.
8: Append successor array’s entries with its index to form a list, L
9: Split L, create flag over split output and scan the flag to find
new ids per vertex, store new ids in C.
10: Find supervertex ids of u and v for each edge using C.
11: Remove edge from edge-list if u, v have same supervertex id.
12: Remove duplicate edges using split over new u, v and w.
13: Compact and create the new edge-list and weight list .
14: Build the vertex list from the newly formed edge-list.
15: Call the MST Algorithm on
```

Author:

```
Vibhav Vineet    
Pawan Harish    
Suryakant Patidar    
P. J. Narayanan
```

[Source](http://cvit.iiit.ac.in/papers/Vibhav09Fast.pdf)

Comment: Question too, isn't it? @Fabinout

Comment: Plus, MST stands for STD in French, so... Even harder than one can think. @Jayram

Comment: Doesn't it have memory complexity O(E)?

Answer (score 0):

There is a connection between Prim's MST algorithm and Dijkstra's single source shortest path algorithm, that is already utilized in BOOST Graph Library implementation of Prim's algorithm for MSTs:

whereas in Dijkstra's algorithm the cost function for a vertex $v$ in the priority queue when going over the most recently popped vertex $u$ is $\L(s,u)+|(u,v)|$, it is the same algorithm, however with $|(u,v)|$ as the cost function that yields the MST instead of the shortest path tree.

The memory footprint is linear in the number of vertices and the way to go would be to take an implementation of Dijkstra's algorithm and modify the cost function accordingly or, use the BOOST Graph Library implementation of Prim's MST algorithm.